# Kiss on the cheek or a cheek?

Tags: articles

> Instead of shaking her hand, kiss her on **the** cheek.

Why do we say "the" instead of "a"?

If we say "the", which cheek are we talking about? Shouldn't it be "a"?

Comment: Well, if someone were to suggest "kiss him on a cheek" one might think there are more than two cheeks....maybe four?

Comment: @Mari-LouA  As a contrast to the more usual expression, *"Kiss him on **a** cheek"* deliberately implies that the speaker could not care less which cheek you should kiss him on, that perhaps the gesture is a pure formality or obligation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are cases when we use the definite article even though there is a pair of possible things referred to. In such cases, it does not matter much which particular thing is described:

> Finally, Sheriff Hughes eased over to **the** side of the road and stopped the engine.

There are two sides, but it's irrelevant in this situation. It's just "the side of the road that a driver chooses to stop by in such a situation".

> I looked him in **the** eye and said, "I don't give a rat's ass what you think".

Again, there are two eyes but still we say "in **the** eye". [Quirk et al.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Comprehensive_Grammar_of_the_English_Language) write that the expression "I looked him in **an** eye" would be appropriate when spoken by, say, an ophthalmologist.

Again, there's the proverb "Beauty is in **the** eye of the beholder". The beholder has two eyes, but we say "the eye".